# How do I pass my json data to table views and other view controllers?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, swift4

I have a main view controller called as HomeController(). There is a grouped table view with three sections. The first section should display data from my JSON file. To give an Idea, I want to display a list of tv series seasons like season1, season2, season3 in my first section.

If a user clicks on season 1, a new view controller will be pushed which contains a table view with rows displaying the titles of season 1 episodes. If user taps on an episode, again a new VC will be pushed where it will display the episode title in UILabel and episode summary in a text view.

[image: My main controller]

[image: My second controller which will display the titles of the selected season episodes]

[image: My third controller where episode title and summary will be displayed]

Currently I'm passing static data like below

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let destVC = EpisodeTextController()
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        destVC.episodeTitleLabel.text = "Minimum Viable product"
        destVC.textView.text = "Basic text"
    }
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destVC, animated: true)
}
```

Here is my basic JSON file

```
{
    "Seasons": [
        {
            "Season Name": "season1",
            "Season Desccription": "season description",
            "Episodes": [
                {
                    "title": "title of episode1",
                    "desc": "description of episode1"
                },
                {
                    "title": "title of episode2",
                    "desc": "description of episode2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Season Name": "Season 2",
            "Season Desccription": "season description",
            "Episodes": [
                {
                    "title": "title of episode1",
                    "desc": "description of episode1"
                },
                {
                    "title": "ttile of episode2",
                    "desc": "description of episode2"
                },
                {
                    "title": "episode3",
                    "desc": "description"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my model object

```
struct Show: Codable {

    let seasons: String
    let episodes: [String]
    let episodeTitle: String
    let episodeSummary: String
}
```

I don't know whether this right or wrong

Comment: This question will be closed any moment by the community as it shows no attempt/research. Edit your question and show what code you have so far, explain what the issue with it is and the question will be better received and likely will get a useful answer

Comment: why would you want to pass around the JSON? assuming you have already decoded it so why not just pass the different parts of the object? seems to me you have 2 arrays (datasources for a UITableViewController) and a single element which you would use on your normal UIViewController. really need to see what you have tried to do,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take 3 viewcontroller 
 1. HomeViewController: You show only season listing data (Using tableview datasource and delegate )

2. EpisodesViewController: If user select any row like user just select any Season, then you can also show the all Episodes of that season, you should pass that data from HomeViewController to EpisodesViewController
3. EpisodesDetailsViewController :
   If any Episode is selected then you should send only the details json data
   from  EpisodesViewController to EpisodesDetailsViewController
   And you just show data in this page 
   This is the steps you have to follow

If you have any problem, please comment here 
my email id is : sudebsarkar21@gmail.com, contact here